# How to change the value of the variable in this function without making a new function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
function SlideShow(area) {
    var SlideImg = new Array('img1', 'img2');
    var SlideArea = document.getElementById(area);
    for (i = 0; i < SlideImg.length; i++) {
        if (SlideImg[i] == SlideImg[0]) {
            var classname = 'active';
        } else {
            var classname = 'not-active';
        }
        var html = '<img src="images/room/' + SlideImg[i] + '.jpg" id="' + SlideImg[i] + '" class="' + classname + '" />';
        SlideArea.innerHTML += html;
    }
    var a = 1;

    function RunSlide() {
        var before = a - 1;
        if (a > SlideImg.length - 1) {
            a = 0;
        }
        ImgBefore = document.getElementById(SlideImg[before]);
        ImgBefore.className = 'not-active';
        ImgNext = document.getElementById(SlideImg[a]);
        ImgNext.className = 'active';
        a++;
    }
    var run = setInterval(RunSlide, 5000);
}
```

How to change the `a` value? Because the `a` variable is not in the Global scope, can I access it from another function? 
I want to access it, but don't want to declare the `a` variable as a global.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand the question. Is it not just a case of declaring `a` outside of `SlideShow`?

Comment: Because the `a` variable is not in the Global scope, can I access it from another function?

Comment: Correct, by declaring it within `SlideShow`, only that function (and `RunSlide`) can access it. Declare it outside of the function, and it will be accessible globally

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the variable is local to the function, so you have to expose a function outside to be able to access it.

You can for example put this last in the function to make it return a function that can set the variable:

```
function SlideShow(area) {
  ...
  return function(value){ a = value; };
}
```

Usage:

```
var setA = SlideShow(something);
```

Then later you can use the function:

```
setA(42);
```

Comment: Can you edit my code with your code? I think it's interesting one

Comment: @EgaRana: I'm sitting by a pad, so I don't have great editing capabilities, but I made the example a bit clearer.

Comment: This is fascinating, although it does require having a global variable to hold the returned function reference

Comment: @freefaller you have same opinion with me hehe

Comment: @freefaller: You need to keep a reference to something somewhere which ever solution you use. Whether the reference is kept globally or not with this solution depends on how you use it. You could wrap that code in a function to keep it from going into the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, declare `var a;` outside of `SlideShow` and then it will be globally accessible.

Remember that it will still require resetting within the functin with `a = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

If you can make the scope of the a variable global, then you should be able to.  Instead of declaring in your function, just reference variable and declare in the "< head >" of your page instead.  See my example and this I tested and clicking diff links changes value of variable and displays on page.

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
<script language="javascript">
var a = -1;

function changeVar(value) {
  a = value;
  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = a;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test page</h1>
<a href="#" onclick="changeVar(2);">Click me (2)</a> <br />
<a href="#" onclick="changeVar(5);">Click me (5)</a> <br />
<a href="#" onclick="changeVar(9);">Click me (9)</a> <br />
<hr>
<h1>Value for a is: <div id="test1"></div></h1>

<!-- really test by including function later on page -->
<script language="javascript">
function SlideShow(area) {
    var SlideImg = new Array('img1', 'img2');
    var SlideArea = document.getElementById(area);
    for (i = 0; i < SlideImg.length; i++) {
        if (SlideImg[i] == SlideImg[0]) {
            var classname = 'active';
        } else {
            var classname = 'not-active';
        }
        var html = '<img src="images/room/' + SlideImg[i] + '.jpg" id="' + SlideImg[i] + '" class="' + classname + '" />';
        SlideArea.innerHTML += html;
    }
    a = 1;  // removed declaration of a and just using a from prior declaration

    function RunSlide() {
        var before = a - 1;
        if (a > SlideImg.length - 1) {
            a = 0;
        }
        ImgBefore = document.getElementById(SlideImg[before]);
        ImgBefore.className = 'not-active';
        ImgNext = document.getElementById(SlideImg[a]);
        ImgNext.className = 'active';
        a++;
    }
    var run = setInterval(RunSlide, 5000);
}
</script>
</html>
```

You cannot access the variable itself if declared in the function because it's scope is LOCAL. See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

However, there is a way you could tweak your function to set a value of another element on the page, then others can reference that value.  Using same code snippet for your script, when a is updated you can set the value of a hidden field on your page, and then others can reference that value.  Any other way I think you have to declare it outside the function.

**ALTERNATE 1:**

```
<!-- really test by including function later on page -->
<script language="javascript">
function SlideShow(area) {
    var SlideImg = new Array('img1', 'img2');
    var SlideArea = document.getElementById(area);
    for (i = 0; i < SlideImg.length; i++) {
        if (SlideImg[i] == SlideImg[0]) {
            var classname = 'active';
        } else {
            var classname = 'not-active';
        }
        var html = '<img src="images/room/' + SlideImg[i] + '.jpg" id="' + SlideImg[i] + '" class="' + classname + '" />';
        SlideArea.innerHTML += html;
    }
    var a = 1;

    function RunSlide() {
        var before = a - 1;
        if (a > SlideImg.length - 1) {
            a = 0;
        }
        ImgBefore = document.getElementById(SlideImg[before]);
        ImgBefore.className = 'not-active';
        ImgNext = document.getElementById(SlideImg[a]);
        ImgNext.className = 'active';
        a++;
        // set value of element on page so others can reference
        document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = a;  // or set a hidden field
    }
    var run = setInterval(RunSlide, 5000);
}
</script>
```

The other way you might be able to do it is declare a return for your function with the value of a, and callers can ignore it if they want and others can retrieve it.  This may not work with your setTimeOut re-calling the RunSlide function.  I tried another inner function within SlideShow but that didn't seem to return a either.  Original scoping suggestion remains.

Comment: Thanks four your code Mike, I appreciate it. I was try this code before for my SlideShow program before I change it to that code above. But can I access the variable without declare the `a` variable to global scope?

Comment: Added some more examples and link about scope above.  Answer is "no" you cannot access the variable if not global, but there are workarounds as noted above.